# outlook 2010 rules selectivly not processing.

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, rules, exchange-2003

I had a set of rules that worked great for our old crm, recreated the rules for our new crm and they dont work for squat.  If we use a single rule to clump all messages from the crm system to a pst folder it works fine.  If we want to seperate by queue ie body contins ...  it fails.  it may run 1 of the rules but wont run them all properly.

I have tried from ...  with words in the body ..   / move to ... set category ...
through specified account ... with words in the body ... / set category ...

even when it was server side only they still failed to run properly. Any suggestions as to whats going on? I have completely deleted all rules and started fresh with no improvement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I could find out it appears to be an incompatibility between exchange 2003 and outlook 2010.  I ended up having to use vba to create a script I could run in the rules. Since user@domain.com worked for catching all emails involved I am able to route as needed through the script.  Its a little buggy, every now and then it errors for no reason but restarting the rule keeps it working right.  until upgrades come and fix the issue Im stuck with this.  works well enough though.